# Why cannot my c++ thread pool accelerate my program?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I tried to implement a c++ thread pool according to some notes made by others, the code is like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <glog/logging.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class ThreadPool {
public:
    ThreadPool(const ThreadPool&) = delete;
    ThreadPool(ThreadPool&&) = delete;
    ThreadPool& operator=(const ThreadPool&) = delete;
    ThreadPool& operator=(ThreadPool&&) = delete;
    ThreadPool(uint32_t capacity=std::thread::hardware_concurrency(), 
            uint32_t n_threads=std::thread::hardware_concurrency()
            ): capacity(capacity), n_threads(n_threads) {
        init(capacity, n_threads);
    }

    ~ThreadPool() noexcept {
        shutdown();
    }

    void init(uint32_t capacity, uint32_t n_threads) {
        CHECK_GT(capacity, 0) << "task queue capacity should be greater than 0";
        CHECK_GT(n_threads, 0) << "thread pool capacity should be greater than 0";
        for (int i{0}; i < n_threads; ++i) {
            pool.emplace_back(std::thread([this] {
                std::function<void(void)> task;
                while (!this->stop) {
                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->q_mutex);
                        task_q_empty.wait(lock, [&] {return this->stop | !task_q.empty();});
                        if (this->stop) break;
                        task = this->task_q.front();
                        this->task_q.pop();
                        task_q_full.notify_one();
                    }
                    // auto id = std::this_thread::get_id();
                    // std::cout << "thread id is: " << id << std::endl;
                    task();
                }
            }));
        }
    }

    void shutdown() {
        stop = true;
        task_q_empty.notify_all();
        task_q_full.notify_all();
        for (auto& thread : pool) {
            if (thread.joinable()) {
                thread.join();
            }
        }
    }

    template<typename F, typename...Args>
    auto submit(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))> {
        using res_type = decltype(f(args...));
        std::function<res_type(void)> func = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto task_ptr = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<res_type()>>(func);
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(q_mutex);
            task_q_full.wait(lock, [&] {return this->stop | task_q.size() <= capacity;});
            CHECK (this->stop == false) << "should not add task to stopped queue\n";
            task_q.emplace([task_ptr]{(*task_ptr)();});
        }
        task_q_empty.notify_one();
        return task_ptr->get_future();
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::thread> pool;
    std::queue<std::function<void(void)>> task_q;
    std::condition_variable task_q_full;
    std::condition_variable task_q_empty;
    std::atomic<bool> stop{false};
    std::mutex q_mutex;
    uint32_t capacity;
    uint32_t n_threads;
};


int add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}

int main() {
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    int n_threads = 1;
    ThreadPool tp;
    tp.init(n_threads, 1024);
    std::vector<std::future<int>> res;
    for (int i{0}; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        res.push_back(tp.submit(add, i, i+1));
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (auto &el : res) {
        el.get();
        // cout << el.get() << endl;
    }

    tp.shutdown();
    cout << "processing: "
        << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t2 - t1).count() 
        << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that, when I set `n_threads=1`, the program takes the same length of time as I set `n_threads=4`. Since my gpu has 72 kernels (from the `htop` command), I believe the 4 thread would be faster than the 1 thread settings. What is the problem with this implementation of the thread pool please?

Comment: Seems your threadpool implementation is faulty. Your test case  is also not ideal.

Comment: @seccpur Hi, would you please point out the fault and post an answer?

Comment: The tasks are so trivial that the threads are spending all their time waiting for their turn to remove items from the queue, so they are basically running in series, not parallel.

Comment: @RaymondChen Hi, Would you please post an answer and tell me how I could cope with this problem ?

Comment: The problem is that your tasks are so small that all of the time is spent in bookkeeping overhead. Instead of 1000000 tasks that each perform a single addition operation, create, say 100 tasks that each perform 10000 addition operations.

Answer (score 1):

I found few issues:

1) Use ORing instead of the bitwise operation in the **both** conditional-variable waits:

```
Replace this -  `task_q_empty.wait(lock, [&] {return this->stop | !task_q.empty();});`
By - `task_q_empty.wait(lock, [&] {return this->stop || !task_q.empty();});`
```

2) Use notify_all() in place of notify_one() in init() and submit().
3) Two condition_variables is unnecessary here, use only `task_q_empty`.
4) Your use case is not ideal. Switching of the threads may outweigh adding of two integers, it may appear more the threads longer the execution time. Test in optimized mode. Try scenario like this to simulate longer process:

```
int add(int a, int b) { this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200)); return a + b; }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Would you please give  a bit explanation on why `notify_all` is better than `notify_one` here?

Comment: Because there is no guarantee that the signal has selectively gone to the idle thread. That way in your code, much of the idle threads may be unnecessary waiting for the signal. By broadcasting to all the threads, the idle thread has more chance of getting a new task.

Comment: But I got the program locked up when I changed `task_q_empty.notify_one()` to `task_q_empty.notify_all()`, how could this be?

Comment: You have to change for both task_q_empty and task_q_full, else you won't get the benefits of multiple threads.

Comment: Yes, I tried, after changing both, I found that the program get locked up, so I changed them one by one and found that if I change `task_q_empty` and with whatever state of the other condition variable, the program will get locked up. Would you please have a look at this ?

Comment: Reduce the number of loops to confirm there isn't a deadlock. You have to change the bitwise operations as well. Reduce delay from 200ms to some smaller value , else it may look as if the program has frozen. You can print something when each task has completed executing.